# Set screen position to center of screen

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am using a tile based game and also used a joystick. Using joystick sprite body move perfectly but tile map can not scroll.

```
-(void)setCenterOfScreen:(b2Vec2)position
{
    int x=MAX(position.x*PTM_RATIO, size.width/2);
    int y=MAX(position.y*PTM_RATIO, size.height/2);


    int x1=MIN(x, (theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width-size.width/2));
    int y1=MIN(y, (theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height-size.height/2));


    b2Vec2 goodpoint=b2Vec2(x1,y1);
    NSLog(@"GoodPoint X: %f",goodpoint.x);
    NSLog(@"GoodPoint Y: %f",goodpoint.y);


    b2Vec2 differ=b2Vec2((size.width/2-goodpoint.x),(size.height/2-goodpoint.y));
    position=differ;
}
```

Is it true logic?
Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this very well written tutorial about tile maps, it does not use a joystick but it is very easy to change the code around so that it does (I have done so myself). 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d